# Dynamic Linker does not resolve symbol although the library is already loaded

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I stumbled over the following problem in my large-grown project: I have a set of libraries which depend on each other and on external libraries. Of one dependency ("libvtkCommonCore-*.so"), there are different variants, which need to be used interchangeably. The variants have different suffixes ("libvtkCommonCore-custom1.so", "libvtkCommonCore-custom2.so" and so on). Thus I cannot link the library, which needs symbols from it, directly to the providing library. Rather I link the application of the library which uses it to the appropriate variant and then load my own library.

This approach generally works but fails under some circumstances and I'm a bit lost while finding out what goes wrong.

This situation is working:
[Sketch of situation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MpQp.png)
("libA" needs symbols from "libvtkCommonCore". It is loaded at run time by the constructor of some static object in "libB" using a "dlopen" call with flags RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL. libvtkCommonCore* and libB were linked at build time to an executable)

This situation now ceases to work:
[Sketch of situation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jN1h.png)
(actually the same as before but complicated by the fact that libvtkCommonCore* and libB are linked to another library libC at build time. This library is loaded from an executable at run time using "dlopen")

I investigated the case by setting LD_DEBUG to "files", "symbols" and/or "binding" and study the output. It reveals that libvtkCommonCore* is loaded, initialized and kept in memory all the time and before libA is loaded. When the linked tries to resolve "SymbolX" in libA, it does not search libvtkCommonCore, although it did for other libraries which needed the same symbol.

Note: I use Linux (Ubuntu 20) with the recent Gcc and CMake. Both the executable in situation 1 and "libC" in situation 2 were built with the flags "-Wl,--add-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed".

Note 2: if I launch the executable in situation 2 with LD_PRELOAD=libvtkCommonCore-custom1.so set, no errors appear.

I would be grateful for any hint how to continue debugging this issue.

A minimum example of the problem is comprised by these files:

libvtkCommonCore-custom1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void SymbolX()
{
    std::cout<<"This just does nothing useful."<<std::endl;
}
```

libA.cpp:

```
void SymbolX(); // in libvtkCommonCore-custom1.so

struct LibAStaticObject
{
    LibAStaticObject()
    {
        SymbolX();
    }
} libAStaticObject;
```

libB.cpp:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

class LibALoader
{
public:
    LibALoader()
    {
        void *handle = dlopen ( "libA.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NODELETE );
        if ( !handle ) 
        {
            std::cerr<<"Could not load module library libA!\nReason: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        }
    }
} libAloader;
```

libC.cpp

```
/*empty*/
```

executable_situation1.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"starting."<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

executable_situation2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

class LibCLoader
{
public:
    LibCLoader()
    {
        void *handle = dlopen ( "libC.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL|RTLD_NODELETE );
        if ( !handle ) 
        {
            std::cerr<<"Could not load module library libC.so!\nReason: " << dlerror() << std::endl;
        }
    }
} libCloader;

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"starting."<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(vtkCommonCore-custom1 SHARED libvtkCommonCore-custom1.cpp)

add_library(A SHARED libA.cpp)

add_library(B SHARED libB.cpp)
target_link_libraries(B dl)

add_library(C SHARED libC.cpp)
target_link_libraries(C vtkCommonCore-custom1 B)
set_target_properties(C PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--add-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries")

add_executable(executable_situation1 executable_situation1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable_situation1 vtkCommonCore-custom1 B)
set_target_properties(executable_situation1 PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,--add-needed -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries") #"-Wl,--no-as-needed")

add_executable(executable_situation2 executable_situation2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(executable_situation2 dl)
```

Run it by these commands:

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build 
$ cmake .. && make 
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./executable_situation1 
This just does nothing useful. 
starting. 
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./executable_situation2 
./executable_situation2: symbol lookup error: ./libA.so: undefined symbol: _Z7SymbolXv
```

Comment: I think, at least I identified the problem. It is about the scope during dynamic linking. According to [here](http://log.or.cz/?p=129): (a) in situation 1, the vtkCommonCore library is placed in the global scope when linked to the main executable; (b) in situation 2, it is in the local scope of libC. For some reason, when libB loads libA, the scope only contains libA and the libraries of the executable (global scope).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the problem is that in situation 2 the libvtkCommonCore is not in the lookup scope of libA while in situation 1 it is in the global scope.

The only (probably ugly) solution I found was to put in a kind of a stub library that loads libvtkCommonCore along with libB using "dlopen" with option "RTLD_GLOBAL". This places libvtkCommonCore in the global lookup scope. The new library is then linked to libC instead of its direct dependencies.